# How to select a button by a specific string within it's label with Selenium(python)?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm currently working on my final project for my a levels. I am currently making a selenium bot which is supposed to scrape Instagram stories (take screenshots of them). I have got past all of the logging in process alongside cookies and what not but I am now stuck.

I would like to click on the first available story which hasn't been viewed yet, up to this point I was able to do everything with xpaths but it doesn't look possible here.

However, I found that the button labels include the string ", not seen." shown here:
[story button html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ9Pv.png)

Is there a way to specifically search for this string in selenium so I can click on it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either one of these locators. Here we're just looking for the substring, ", not seen" in the `aria-label` attribute.

```
button[aria-label*=', not seen'] # By.CSS_SELECTOR
//button[contains(@aria-label, ', not seen')] # By.XPATH
```